# Supporting iPhone 5 with iOS7 and iPhone6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, iphone-6

I'm not getting my application to work on both iPhone6 with iOS8 and iPhone5 with iOS7. Maybe it is the case I remove support for iOS7 but I don't think it is a good reason.

I'm working on a legacy code and I was an Android developer so I don't fully understand iOS.
But my is case is, I'm trying to support iPhone6 and to do that I added a new XIB on 'Launch Screen File' on project configs. Before that my code was working great on iPhone4, 5 and 6. But after that all the screens stopped to auto resize to fulfill the iPhone6 screen and on iPhone5 when running iOS7 the apps shows black bars on top and bottom of the screen. But with iOS 8 it runs OK.

[image: iPhone 5 with iOS 7 showing black bars on top and bottom]
[image: iPhone 5 with iOS 8 runs OK]
[image: iPhone 6 runs OK]

I fixed the resize problem for iPhone6 adding the correct constraints on xibs. But I`m not able to fix this iPhone5 problem.

And despite this error, another strange behaviour I'm facing is that I'm unable to send the application to Apple Store because it says it is not currently supporting iPhone5. The xCode error is:

[image: Organizer error when deploying app]

This error looks like outdated because the second link is not working.

The only similar erros I found, about how to support iPhone5, are from 2012 or 2013 before iPhone6, and they basically tells to add new launch image for the iPhone5 size, as my app was already running on iPhone5 so I think it is not the problem.

[image: Launch images, I just did't added for Retine HD 4.7 and 5.5 because they should use the xib]

So, what am I doing wrong? Or what config should I change to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your info.plist say about launch screen file(s)? iOS will consult the property list to know which files are supposed to be the launch image; just having one with the filename LaunchImage isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Tommy: The only entry on info.plist about launch images it one named 'Launch screen interface file base name' of type String and the value is the name of my xib for iphone6. Should the info.plist have any other info besides this?

Comment: I don't offhand know what Xcode calls it as a natural string but if you locate your info.plist in the Finder and open it from there, look for either `UILaunchImageFile` or `UILaunchImages`. Assuming neither is present, try adding `UILaunchImageFile` of type string, with value `LaunchImage` (I don't think you'll need to add .png but you may). Even better: if this project is under source control, rewind a little and crib the correct key/value pair from there. I think what has probably happened is that Xcode has removed the old key when you added the XIB-based screen.

Comment: @Tommy, these both keys are really missing on my Info.plist li I added this '<key>UILaunchImageFile</key><string>LaunchImage.png</string>' to the Info.plist file. I also tried removing the .png extension and adding a image file to the project with this name. But the app still opens with black bars on iPhone5.

Comment: Then at this point I'm confident it's the absence of the info.plist key that iOS 7 and below look for, and confident that my instructions on how to fix that are invalid. I'm at work right now which prevents anything but the briefest comment; will try to return later.

Comment: @Tommy, I have some updates here. I set the 'Launch Images Source' to doesn't use the assets catalog, so now, the only launch image is the xib configured on 'Launch Screen File'. With that, and with out adding the 'UILaunchImageFile' key on the Info.plist, the app is now opening correctly on all iPhones (including the iPhone5 with iOS7). But if I add the 'UILaunchImageFile' then the black bars are back. But sadly, with or with out the 'UILaunchImageFile', when I try to send the app to AppleStore the organizer still say the app is not optimized for iPhone5.

Comment: @Tommy now I think I managed this... My final version has a Default-568h@2x.png file on root folder, the launch image xib and no 'UILaunchImageFile' key on Info.plist. In this way it is running on the iPhone5 and there is no errors when sending the app to AppleStore. I thought that after setting 'Launch Images Source' to use the xcassets the 'Default' images was not going to be used anymore, so I removed them. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: oh, smart move. Being able to specify the filename in your info.plist is 'new' (as in, from iOS 3.2, not really new) and Default is what the OS would otherwise look for, for legacy support. So, yes, you've found your own answer. Glad I could nudge though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some help from @Tommy to point the way I managed to fix my problem.

Firstly, I think my problem was caused because I had removed all the 'Default.png' images from the project root folder when I configured the 'Launch Images Source' to use the Images.xcassets. Before adding the 'Launch Screen File' this was working. But after I added the 'Launch Screen File' my project stopped working.

So to fix the problem I had to readd the Default-568h@2x.png image to project's root folder and set 'Launch Images Source' to 'Don't use assets catalog'. That way, as I understand, the Default-568h@2x tells xCode that the project is optimized to iPhone5 runnning iOS7, and all other devices or the iPhone5 running iOS8 uses the 'Launch Screen File'.

Comment: After scouring Stackoverflow for the last few days this answer finally snapped it into place. I have had problems with the "LaunchScreen" entry in the plist before and have never used a launch screen before. Deleting this entry from the plist solved the issue immediately. Remember that the launch screen is very different from the launch images in the xcassets folder